# When does Dalvik heap size increase?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I recently encountered some cases where heap size was increased without performing GC.
Example - At the beginning, 746KB(evaluated using Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) of free space was available. 512KB was required to allocate a Bitmap of size 512*512(RGB_565). Without doing a de-frag, the heap size was increased. The free space in the heap was just reduced by 3 KB. Similar pattern was repeated 20 times in a row. No GC message was printed in-between these allocations. Each alloc took ~1ms of time.

```
for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) {
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  System.out.println("Free space:"+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
  System.out.println("Heap size:"+Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
  list.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(512, 512, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565));
  System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-start);
}
```

Doesn't Dalvik always perform a GC before increasing heap size?

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if any more information is required.